# How to connect PC and iPhone through WiFi (FTP, etc.)?

Tags: networking, firewall, ftp, file-transfer, iphone

I live in a building with one internet  connection but every apartment has its own router. The internet works fine in all my devices (PCs, laptops, phones, etc.), but when I try to connect my iPhone to a PC through FTP apps or AirDroid (FTP or HTTP 192.168.0.x:8080), I'm unable to access my iPhone IP.

Even when I try to pint that ip in CMD, it says: "Destination host unreachable".

My house router is TP-Link Wireless N Router WR840N.

I have PC connected through Ethernet (Wired), and other laptops connected through WiFi. I  can't access my iPhone IP in any device.

Few years ago, when I was living in a separate house, I can easily use this FTP method using WinSCP or even the internet browser.

What's the problem?